# how to connect multiple markers to a single location using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pentaho

I wanted to connect multiple markers to a single location using javascript.

I have written the code below and I am getting markers that are getting connected sequentially (as in the image provided).

FYI, I am a beginner in working with javascript and google maps.

I wanted to connect the markers to the following location **['134.56.32.13',19.0760,72.8777]** 
where, 
'134.56.32.13' is the example IP address
19.0760 is the latitude
72.8777 is the longitude.

This is a link i found helpful in connecting the locations -
[Connect Multiple markers with polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291764/connect-multiple-markers-with-polyline)

```
var locations = [
  ['123.134.67.145', 22.5726, 88.3639],
  ['140.91.57.132', 28.7041, 77.1025],
  ['110.191.167.130', 13.0827, 80.2707],
  ['192.168.151.151', 12.9716, 77.5946]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.75, 77.94),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

The markers are getting connected sequentially.This is the image.

[image]

This is how the output should look like

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how do i connect the markers to a single location?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want all the markers point to the same location? So just change `locations` array.

Comment: If several markers share the exact same location, you need to use something like this https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski , the data in the locations array is being sequentially connected. I want them to be connected to a single destination and not with each other. flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition()) is pushing each position one after the other and is connecting to the position that was just added to the flightPlanCoordinates array

Comment: Oh I see, check out marker clustering https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: How will marker clustering help solve this problem? It does help on zooming in and out, but how does it connect the markers to a single destination?
I would like to know on how to get an output, as in the second image.

Comment: Exactly. By using marker clustering if they all point to the same location it will act the way you want. Trust me, I've done it myself.

Comment: @UtkarshTandon But in your example markers do not point to the same location, so this is very confusing.

Comment: Which point (in your posted code) do you want to be the one that links to all the others?  Did you want arrows on the polylines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest to add that entry to your array, then skip it, and create two point polylines starting there and going to each (other) marker in the array:

```
var locations = [
  ['134.56.32.13', 19.0760, 72.8777],
  ['123.134.67.145', 22.5726, 88.3639],
  ['140.91.57.132', 28.7041, 77.1025],
  ['110.191.167.130', 13.0827, 80.2707],
  ['192.168.151.151', 12.9716, 77.5946]
];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  if (i != 0) {
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
      marker.getPosition()
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      icons: [{
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        },
        offset: '50%'
      }],
      strokeColor: "#ff0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lyp1n3eb/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['134.56.32.13', 19.0760, 72.8777],
  ['123.134.67.145', 22.5726, 88.3639],
  ['140.91.57.132', 28.7041, 77.1025],
  ['110.191.167.130', 13.0827, 80.2707],
  ['192.168.151.151', 12.9716, 77.5946]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.75, 77.94),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
// create polylines
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  if (i != 0) {
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
      marker.getPosition()
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      icons: [{
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        },
        offset: '50%'
      }],
      strokeColor: "#ff0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```